# how to create interactive Donut graph with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've been working for a few hours now and I can't get my donut graph drawn with js anyone can help me with that any solution i want when selected checkbox add 25% when slected two checkbox add +25% thank you .

[image: Dount graph i want to create]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var el = document.getElementById('graph'); // get canvas

var options = {
    percent:  el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
    size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 220,
    lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 15,
    rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.textContent = options.percent + '%';
    
if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

el.appendChild(span);
el.appendChild(canvas);

ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

//imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
        percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
        ctx.stroke();
};

drawCircle('#efefef', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);

$(".chkBox").on("click", function(){
    var dp = parseFloat($("#graph").attr("data-percent"));
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $("#graph").attr("data-percent", dp + 25);
    }else{
        $("#graph").attr("data-percent", dp - 25);
    }
    span.textContent = parseFloat($("#graph").attr("data-percent")) + '%';
    console.log($("#graph").attr("data-percent"));
    drawCircle('#efefef', options.lineWidth, 100 / 100);
    drawCircle('#555555', options.lineWidth, parseFloat($("#graph").attr("data-percent")) / 100);
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="chart" id="graph" data-percent="0"></div>
<label for="id_1">A</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" id="id_1" /><br/>
<label for="id_2">B</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" id="id_2" /><br/>
<label for="id_3">C</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" id="id_3" /><br/>
<label for="id_4">D</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkBox" id="id_4" />
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position:relative;
    margin:80px;
    width:220px; height:220px;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
span {
    color:#555;
    display:block;
    line-height:220px;
    text-align:center;
    width:220px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-left:5px;
}

input {
    width: 200px;
}
```